# What code should I use where I used db_query()?

Tags: database, 8

I want to execute `SHOW TABLES` in Drupal 8. In Drupal 7, I would use `db_query("SHOW TABLES")`, which is deprecated in Drupal 8.

What should I use for Drupal 8?

Comment: Note that this is pretty specific to MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

As quick replacement for queries on the database Drupal uses by default, you can use the following code.

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

$db = Drupal::database();
$result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
```

Keep in mind that:

- `db_query()` will not be removed before Drupal 9 goes off; you can still use it, even if it is preferable to refactor your code to be more object oriented
- The code I shown should be used in legacy procedural code; when possible, you should consider refactoring it to be object oriented and use Drupal 8 [services and Dependency Injection Container](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/container/8)

Answer (score 4):

You can still run arbitrary queries against the database. `db_query` is deprecated because it does not go well with the dependency injection pattern found elsewhere in D8.

All you need to do is getting the database object.

**Default database**

This should fit almost everyone, unless you are trying to run the query on a different connection.

```
$db = \Drupal::service('database');
$result = $db->query('SHOW TABLES'); // You can run the good old fetchAll(), etc on the $result now.
```

**Other databases**

If you want to run the query on a different database connection,  just get the service spawn, and you can run `query()` on it.

**Examples**

I could find several examples from the Backup and migrate module's [`MySQLiSource` class](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/backup_migrate/tree/vendor/backupmigrate/core/src/Source/MySQLiSource.php).